# SWT: custom MessageBox / more text / how to get the icons?

Tags: icons, swt

i want to display a second, not bold, text in my MessageBox, like seen for OSX here: http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/NR/rdonlyres/1EA4CC0C-F0B9-45D3-BD2C-EF2C430E3FAD/15107/error2.gif

Is there a way to do this with MessageBox? If not, I would create my own Dialog, problem is that i don't know how to load the appropriate icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MessageBox is fairly constrained in its functionality.  You can get the system icon from the Display class and then set it in a label:

```
final Image warningImage = getShell().getDisplay().getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_WARNING);

final Label imageLabel = new Label(dialogArea, SWT.NONE);
imageLabel.setImage(image);
```